# Furnace blower motor starts but then starts clicking and eventually stops with a loud buzz

Tags: furnace, blower

I have a Bryant furnace with a multi-speed blower.  Yesterday I just replaced the capacitor and confirmed it is still working.  The furnace turns on fine and the blower motor starts up when expected.  About 5 minutes in you begin to hear a small clicking noise from the motor which then slowly gets louder and louder.  About 3 minutes later the buzzing gets really loud and the motor slowly stops turning and its just buzzing.  The furnace then shuts itself off.  Unfortunately I can't seem to get an amp meter in anywhere to test the draw but the issue is consistent.  There is no buzzing from the relay on the circuit board and the fan has not yet changed over from high heat to low heat.  Is the motor bad or is there something in the circuit board that is bad?  Its hard to test since the circuit board is in the compartment that the blower is in.  Thanks

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'm guessing that the blower bearings are dying, and get worse with heat. But, it's hard to tell from here.

Comment: Thanks.  That explains why it took longer to freeze up when I only had the fan on and no heat.

Answer (score 2):

The bearings need to be oil at least during your annual maintenance.....the what? Yep once a year your system needs a checkup, just like your car, it needs checked, tuned up and repaired as needed. A lot of people don't realize this. The bearings could be sealed and in that case, your motor might need professional help or replacement. If you pull the motor out, look for oiling holes that you drop oil drops into. Your furnace manual would tell or show where they are. The manual or a label on the furnace should also state the type of oil to use. I have a Carrier furace and a label on the blower housing had this info. Bryant, Payne, Carrier and Day And Night are all maufactured by Carrier Corp.

Comment: Looked all over this motor and don't see any oil points.  There are a ton of holes on this fan but nothing that is marked or would even look like oil goes there.  No labels that say it either.  Thanks

Comment: Ended up buying a new motor.  Hopefully the new one will be quieter.

Comment: My Carrier was marked, but the motor wasn't. So I took the motor out and dripped some wd-40 in and handspun it a bit, then some 3-in-1. Its been God for 2 years now. Just dripor spray toward the shaft hole and work it in.

Comment: I almost bought a new motor, but I tried the grease/oil approach first and it worked.